# How can I wait for an object filled asynchronously in Android UI thread without blocking it?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I have a singleton to handle the registration and elimination of an entity Profilo ( a Profile).

This entity is set by passing an identifier and gathering information on the server in an async way.

My problem is that when I have to return my instance of profilo if it's not still loaded it will return null.

```
public class AccountHandler {
    private static AccountHandler istanza = null;

    Context context;
    private boolean logged;
    private Profilo profilo;


    private AccountHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        //initialization
        //setting logged properly
            assignField(this.getName());
        }
    }

    public static AccountHandler getAccountHandler(Context context) {
        if (istanza == null) {
            synchronized (AccountHandler.class) {
                if (istanza == null) {
                    istanza = new AccountHandler(context);
                }
            }
        }
        return istanza;
    }

    public void setAccount(String nickname, String accessingCode) {
        logged = true;
        assignField(nickname);
    }

    //other methods

    private void assignField(String nickname) {
        ProfiloClient profiloClient = new ProfiloClient();
        profiloClient.addParam(Profilo.FIELDS[0], nickname);
        profiloClient.get(new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode,
                                  Header[] headers,
                                  JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject objson = null;
                try {
                    objson = (JSONObject) response.getJSONObject(0);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                AccountHandler accountHandler = AccountHandler.getAccountHandler(context);
    // Profilo is created with a JSONObject
    // **setProfilo is called in async**
                **accountHandler.setProfilo(new Profilo(objson));**
            }

        });
    }


    private void setProfilo(Profilo profilo) {
        this.profilo = profilo;
    }



    public Profilo getProfilo() {
        if( logged && profilo == null)
            //How can I wait that profilo is loaded by the JsonHttpResponseHandler before to return it

        return this.profilo;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `getProfilo` you could use a callback mechanism in which the `AccountHandler` class notifies the caller when the profile has been loaded. e.g.

```
  public void setAccount(String nickname, String accessingCode, MyCallback cb) {
      assignField(nickname, cb);
  }
  private void assignField(String nickname, MyCallback cb) {
      ....
      accountHandler.setProfilo(new Profilo(objson));
      cb.onSuccess(this.profilo);
  }
```

Create an inner Interface `MyCallback` (rename it) in your `AccountHandler` class

```
public class AccountHandler {
    public interface MyCallback {
        void onSuccess(Profilo profile);
    }
}
```

Now whenever you call `setAccount` you will pass the callback and get notified when the profile is available e.g.

```
accountHandler.setAccount("Test", "Test", new AccountHandler.MyCallback() {
        void onSuccess(Profilio profile) {
            // do something with the profile
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't solve with this exactly solution because I needed to make getProfilo returning something. But I've taken the idea of the interface and I put the method onSucces (that I called it profiloReady) in the getProfilo method inside a recursive Handler.

Answer (score 0):

I added, as @Murat K. suggested, an interface to my Class that will provide a method to be call with the object when it is ready to be used.

```
   public class AccountHandler {

    public interface Callback {
            void profiloReady(Profilo profilo);
    }
}
```

This method is called in getProfilo in a Handler that makes recursive calls to getProfilo until profilo is ready to be used, then it call the callback method which class is passed as argument of getProfilo.

```
public void getProfilo(final Callback Callback) {
    if( logged && (profilo == null || !profilo.isReady() ) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getProfilo(Callback);
            }
        }, 500);
    }else
        Callback.profiloReady(profilo);
}
```

Example of getProfilo call

```
public class ProfiloCall implements AccountHandler.MyCallback {

        @Override
        public void profiloReady(Profilo profilo) {
            //Use profilo as needed
            //EXECUTED ONLY WHEN PROFILO IS READY
        }


        public void callerMethod() {
            //useful code
            accountHandler.getProfilo(this);
            //other useful code

        }
    }
```

Comment: this is not good.because if user press back it 's still posting runnables . a new handler will be created when returning to the app again. so you have two handlers now. because you didn't remove callback via
 `handler.removeCallback(runnable) ` or setting `handler =null` in `onDestroy`.you will get NPE for sure.

Comment: @Bishoy Abd
What if I check 
`if(myCallback == null) {
            return;
        }`